# How to trigger ENTER in an OutlineTextField in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I use a scanner that does "ENTER" at the end of the scan.
My OutlinedTextField singleLine is set to true, but when I scan a value,ENTER is not trigger, but a second line is added in the field.
So the "\n" is interpreted as a back line and not as ENTER

The onValueChange is trigger 2 times:

- first time with the value of the scan
- second time with the "\n" at the end of the string

So I have remove the suffix "\n" of the string, but I need trigger the onDone keybordActions

Here is my OutlineTextField

```
OutlinedTextField(
                value = valueScan,
                singleLine = true,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester),
                onValueChange = {
                    if (it.contains("\n")){
                        valueScan = it.removeSuffix("\n")
                    }else{
                        valueScan = it
                    }
                },
                label = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Codebarre"
                    )
                },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                ),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onDone = {
                        keyboardController?.hide()
                        if (listeScan.contains(valueScan)) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                context,
                                "Codebarre $valueScan déjà scanné",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        } else {
                            if (nbScan < scanAFaire) {
                                nbScan++
                                viewModel.listeCodebarre.add(valueScan)
                                listeScan = viewModel.listeCodebarre
                                valueScan = ""
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    context,
                                    "Nombre de scan à faire atteint",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            )
```

I tried to use maxLines instead of singleLine but it doesn't change anything